# SparkR: "Cannot resolve column name..." when adding a new column to Spark data frame

Tags: sparkr

I am trying to add some computed columns to a SparkR data frame, as follows:

```
Orders <- withColumn(Orders, "Ready.minus.In.mins",   
(unix_timestamp(Orders$ReadyTime) - unix_timestamp(Orders$InTime)) / 60)
Orders <- withColumn(Orders, "Out.minus.In.mins", 
(unix_timestamp(Orders$OutTime) - unix_timestamp(Orders$InTime)) / 60)
```

The first command executes ok, and `head(Orders)` reveals the new column. The second command throws the error:

```
15/12/29 05:10:02 ERROR RBackendHandler: col on 359 failed
Error in select(x, x$"*", alias(col, colName)) : 
error in evaluating the argument 'col' in selecting a method for function 
'select': Error in invokeJava(isStatic = FALSE, objId$id, methodName, ...) :
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Cannot resolve column name 
"Ready.minus.In.mins" among (ASAP, AddressLine, BasketCount, CustomerEmail, CustomerID, CustomerName, CustomerPhone, DPOSCustomerID, DPOSOrderID, ImportedFromOldDb, InTime, IsOnlineOrder, LineItemTotal, NetTenderedAmount, OrderDate, OrderID, OutTime, Postcode, ReadyTime, SnapshotID, StoreID, Suburb, TakenBy, TenderType, TenderedAmount, TransactionStatus, TransactionType, hasLineItems, Ready.minus.In.mins);
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$$anonfun$resolve$1.apply(DataFrame.scala:159)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$$anonfun$resolve$1.apply(DataFrame.scala:159)
at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.resolve(DataFrame.scala:158)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$$anonfun$col$1.apply(DataFrame.scala:650)
at org.apa
```

Do I need to do something to the data frame after adding the new column before it will accept another one?

Answer (score 1):

From the link, just use backsticks, when accessing the column, e.g.:

From using

```
df['Fields.fields1']
```

or something, use:

```
df['`Fields.fields1`']
```

Answer (score 0):

Found it here: [spark-issues mailing list archives](https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/spark-issues/201511.mbox/%3CJIRA.12916010.1448420265000.186431.1448420290969@Atlassian.JIRA%3E)

SparkR isn't entirely happy with "." in a column name.